in nifi how to split multiple json data as one json data in one file
I have data coming from ingnition to nifi and than to alloydb. I'm succesfully getting data from ignition to nifi. the output I'm getting is one file with multiple json data into it. I want one json in 1 file
I have to type of table that is abc, pqr, for both table I want same process
This is my json:
{
  "records" : [ {
    "recordtype" : "abc",
    "data" : {
      "Site" : "IgnitionSim",
      "Line" : "FASTLine_102",
      "CERLot" : "",
      "TXID" : "",
       }
  }, {
    "recordtype" : "abc",
    "data" : {
      "Site" : "IgnitionSim",
      "Line" : "FASTLine_102",
      "CERLot" : "",
      "TXID" : "",
         }
  }, {
    "recordtype" : "abc",
    "data" : {
      "Site" : "IgnitionSim",
      "Line" : "FASTLine_102",
      "CERLot" : "",
      "TXID" : "",
          }
  }, {


I want this as as one file should only have only one json
